# Notification feed following Flat feed isn't showing activities

Tags: getstream-io

I have a notification feed like `NOTIFICATIONS:userID` and I have a flat feed `GLOBAL:domain`.

The notification feed is set up to follow the flat feed, but when I push activities to the flat feed they are not coming through to the notification feed. I can't get them to come through the react components or making the API calls directly. Any items in the notification feed come through fine, but not the flat feed.

Is there anything I would have missed when setting up the feeds to make this possible? I'm not sure why it isn't working.

Here's the code used to call getstream:

```golang
// AddNotification writes a feed notification to the provided feed.
func (c *Client) AddNotification(feedID, actor string, n *feed.Notification) error {
    keys := map[string]bool{}
    feeds := make([]stream.Feed, 0)

    for _, s := range n.Streams {
        if s == feed.STREAM_NONE {
            continue
        }

        if _, ok := keys[s.String()]; ok {
            continue
        }

        f, err := c.getstream.FlatFeed(s.String(), feedID)
        if err != nil {
            return errors.Wrapf(err, "failed to get feed %s", feedID)
        }

        keys[s.String()] = true
        feeds = append(feeds, f)
    }

    extra, err := getExtraFromString(n.Content)
    if err != nil {
        return errors.Wrap(err, "failed to marshal extra content")
    }

    appliesAt, err := time.FromProtoTS(n.GetAppliesAt())
    if err != nil {
        return errors.Wrap(err, "failed to cast applies at time")
    }
    activity := stream.Activity{
        Actor:     actor,
        Verb:      n.GetVerb(),
        Object:    n.GetObject(),
        Extra:     extra,
        ForeignID: n.GetIdempotentKey(),
        Time:      stream.Time{Time: appliesAt},
    }

    log.WithFields(log.Fields{
        "activity": activity,
        "feeds":    keys,
    }).Debug("sending request to stream.io")

    if err = c.getstream.AddToMany(activity, feeds...); err != nil {
        return errors.Wrap(err, "error while feeding to stream.io")
    }

    return nil
}
```

Just to explain the code a bit. We have a `feed.Notification` type that allows you to specify what we've called "streams", these are just types that represent the slugs.

In this case, I'm using the `GLOBAL:domain` feed, which the user's `NOTIFICATION:userID` feed is set up to follow.

Comment: can you share the code you use to add activities to the flat feed?

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli have updated my question to contain a code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [batch add docs](https://getstream.io/docs/add_many_activities/?language=go):

> Activities added using this method are not propagated to followers. That is, any other Feeds that follow the Feed(s) listed in the API call will not receive the new Activity.

If you're using batching, you need to specify all feeds you want to add the activity  for. Another way is that you can add to feeds one by one to push to followers.

Comment: Ah okay, so the problem is down to me using `AddToMany`, rather than just iterating that list of feeds and doing individual adds?

Comment: @DavidBond Yes, exactly.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will change my code and try again. If it works I'll come back and mark this as the answer.

Comment: However, there is a subtle difference, if you add one by one they will be different activities. If you want to keep the same activity, you could use to targeting, https://getstream.io/docs/targeting/?language=go If you would like to update later, it will help there.

Comment: Yep, it worked. Thanks again. We're still figuring out exactly how we're implementing the idea of global notifications. So for this use-case just iterating should be fine. I'll check out targeting now

Comment: Good to hear, my pleasure.